# Ubuntu on vmWare: added a new disk, unable to find it

Tags: mount, vmware

The vmware sysadmin added a new disk to a existing (and running) virtual machine with ubuntu.

I paste here info about common command used to understand drive mappings

### Info from vmware console

```
Hard disk 1 - 80 GB - Scsi 0:0
Hard disk 2 - 200 GB - Scsi 0:1
Hard disk 3 - 80 GB - Scsi 0:2
```

The third disk is new new one
I need to format and mount.

More infos follow.

### lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

### cat /proc/partitions

```
major minor  #blocks  name

  11        0    1048575 sr0
   2        0          4 fd0
   8        0   83886080 sda
   8        1     498688 sda1
   8        2          1 sda2
   8        5   83384320 sda5
   8       16  209715200 sdb
   8       17  208983351 sdb1
 252        0   82333696 dm-0
 252        1    1048576 dm-1

$ ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1
```

### sudo rescan-scsi-bus.sh

```
Scanning SCSI subsystem for new devices
Scanning host 0 for  SCSI target IDs  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7, all LUNs
Scanning host 1 for  SCSI target IDs  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7, all LUNs
 Scanning for device 1 0 0 0 ...           
OLD: Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
      Vendor: NECVMWar Model: VMware IDE CDR10 Rev: 1.00
      Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Scanning host 2 for  SCSI target IDs  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7, all LUNs
 Scanning for device 2 0 0 0 ... 
OLD: Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
      Vendor: VMware   Model: Virtual disk     Rev: 1.0 
      Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 02
 Scanning for device 2 0 1 0 ... 
OLD: Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 01 Lun: 00
      Vendor: VMware   Model: Virtual disk     Rev: 1.0 
      Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 02
0 new or changed device(s) found.          
0 remapped or resized device(s) found.          
0 device(s) removed.
```

### sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 80 GiB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x03aba350

Dispositivo Avvio   Start      Fine   Settori  Size Id Tipo
/dev/sda1   *        2048    999423    997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2         1001470 167770111 166768642 79,5G  5 Esteso
/dev/sda5         1001472 167770111 166768640 79,5G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdb: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x78a76f80

Dispositivo Avvio Start      Fine   Settori   Size Id Tipo
/dev/sdb1          2048 417968750 417966703 199,3G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--1604--64--ftp--vg-root: 78,5 GiB, 84309704704 bytes, 164667392 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--1604--64--ftp--vg-swap_1: 1 GiB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

### sudo lsblk -f

```
NAME                                 FSTYPE      LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
fd0                                                                                           
sda                                                                                           
├─sda1                               ext2              5ad72be2-9e4e-4ccc-971f-8efa938b7a57   /boot
├─sda2                                                                                        
└─sda5                               LVM2_member       Afot5Y-kyl3-QesZ-sMgg-dmiL-38dK-kKZJZP 
  ├─ubuntu--1604--64--ftp--vg-root   ext4              eb40816a-26a9-4507-878e-e2fb4de57b37   /
  └─ubuntu--1604--64--ftp--vg-swap_1 swap              935d9909-e290-4229-9c47-e67aa1516709   [SWAP]
sdb                                                                                           
└─sdb1                               ext4              506cf3de-d2da-4970-a2ac-e823eba06987   /bacula
sr0
```

### Problem

**I have no idea how to find the new device**, to format and mount it.

How can I detect new added hardrive?

I've not a previous output of none of these command list of 
- ls /dev/sd*

So I'm here to ask your help

Comment: what does `sudo lsblk -f` say?

Comment: so i guess the `/dev/sdb` is the device your looking for?

Comment: How do you guess it? /dev/sdb already has a sdb1 (/bacula) and this folder/mount point was already here since years

Comment: Could be sda2? It has not file system, if I understand well

Comment: Adding a new disk will give you a `/dev/sdX` not `/dev/sda2` that's a partition! Let me check what fs code is `5`.

Comment: It's not `/dev/sda2` that's the extension parent of `/dev/sda5`!!!

Comment: So I've not a new disk, why?

Comment: Please get back to your admin have them recheck the addition!

Comment: I'm trying this just now with Ubuntu 18 (VMware 6.7).  A SCSI disk rescan including that .sh script does not show the disk.  Trying to not reboot the VM.

Comment: [EDIT TO LAST COMMENT] It seems there's two scripts with the scsitools package (or I need to read the options).  I ran /sbin/rescan-scsi-bus and it definitely ran longer and now I see my new drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that problem was hard disk not really added by sysadmin.

Sorry.

After succesfully adding a new HD, at SCSI 3:0 I can see it as /sdc1